# Подсчет времени в программе.

Tags: c++builder, c, c++

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как осуществить подсчет времени в микросекундах при выполнении определенных пунктов программы в С++ Builder 6.

Answer (score 2):

пишете так:

```
unsigned long StartTime = GetTickCount();
//ваш фрагмент кода
unsigned long Elapsed = GetTickCount() - StartTime;
```

Elapsed - время работы фрагмента кода в милисекундах. 1 секунда = 1000 милисекунд.

Answer (score 2):

На практике (я не беру системы реального времени, встроенные и т.п.) МИКРОсекунды не поймать, т.е. их измерение это самообман. Измеряйте циклы (в милисекундах), затем вычитайте время пустых циклов. Кстати, если считаете вычисления в памяти и делаете много замеров, берите не средний, а лучший результат. Кроме случая, если вам важно учесть среднюю внешнюю нагрузку на систему.

Answer (score 2):

```
   #include <time.h>

    clock_t begin;
    clock_t end;

    begin = clock ();
    //что считаем
    end = clock();

    std::cout<<(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<std::endl;
```

Я делал как-то так.

Answer (score 1):

У `GetTickCount()` точность - 10мс.
Если нужно более точно, воспользуйтесь rdtsc.

Comment: Один тик это не 1мс, и счётчик этот меняется не линейно. Точность - 64мс.

Comment: Вы правы, давно читал об этом, не подумал.